# Multi-dimensional solver

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, integer, solver

Am trying to code a solution to find the full list of vectors `B={b1, b2..b10}`in 10-dimensional space such that (a) each `b1..b10` is an integer between 0 and 30 inclusive; (b) the value of `t(B)  %*%  M  %*%  B` is between  two scalar values `0.98*K` and `K`, where `M` a is given `10x10` matrix.

Brute-force approach as per below runs out of space for an array of this size.

`M<- array(dim=c(30, 10))`

`d <- do.call(expand.grid,lapply(dim(M),seq))`   etc...

Would anyone have ideas on either (a) solvers I could use, or (b) a non-solver approach to address the computational space issue?

Comment: Are `M` and `K` given? Anything special about `M`, e.g. positive definite? Is this homework?

Comment: M and K are given. M is a correlation matrix. This is not homework; trying to solve a real-life problem.

Comment: Why do you need the full list of such vectors, isn't it potentially very large? Are you not trying to maximize/minimize some objective function over that feasible set? Tell us more about your real-life problem.